Where to locate vinyl window screws?
I am currently in the process of contacting my window manufacturer for installation instructions, as the windows I ordered did not come with any (and I want to install them myself).
Many windows have cover plates and obvious places to put screws, but these are flangeless European style casement windows, and I can't see any obvious place to put screws.
I was provided the following cross-section view, and I'm wondering if anyone with experience can tell where the screws should be located?

I've put some marks as to my best guesses.  The red location has a nice large channel, but requires drilling through quite a bit of plastic near the edge of the weather seal.  The blue and green locations are on the oustide of the weather seal and require a bit less drilling, however none of those locations will be flush with any shims later - not sure if that matters or not?
Would appreciate any thoughts people have :)

Ideally, your preferred location for your anchors is marked in blue.
Do not put anchors into the sill of the unit. Locate your jamb anchors about 6" from the top and bottom with at least 1 additional anchor in the center or split  proportionately depending on the height. An anchor should be applied at the center on the top.

Thank you so much for the advice!  I'm wondering how you know blue is the correct location? Just checking - should I drill a hole so that the screw head rests on the outermost layer of vinyl inside the channel?  Also for anchors, I was going to follow the SAWDAC Installation Guide (ie: https://duravu.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/SAWDAC-Installation-Guide.pdf) for anchor placement - for a single casement window, it doesn't show an anchor through the top.  Do you think that is acceptable?

Technically, there is a screw groove just to the right of your blue arrow. That's where you drill. You do not want to damage the exterior air seal. SAWDAC recommends the consensus opinion. If your window is less than 24" wide, it's optional. But that's just me.
